# coordinates out of bound:bufferedimage(getrgb)

Tags: java, image, matrix, rgb, bufferedimage

I have to find the matrix of an image first , I have this code ,that gives me an error here `L[row][col] = image.getRGB(row, col); 
the error is`"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!"
What are the reasons for that error??

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import Jama.EigenvalueDecomposition;
import Jama.Matrix;

public class eigenvalues {

    double L[][], A[];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\lina\\workspace\\eigen\\koala.jpg");

        BufferedImage image= ImageIO.read(file);
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        double[][] L = new double[height][width];

        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
                L[row][col] = image.getRGB(row, col);
            }
        }
        Matrix A=new Matrix(L);
        EigenvalueDecomposition e = A.eig();
        Matrix V = e.getV();
        Matrix D = e.getD();
        System.out.print("A =");
        A.print(9, 6);
        System.out.print("D =");
        D.print(9, 6);
        System.out.print("V =");
        V.print(9, 6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `getRGB()` has this signature

```
public int getRGB(int x, int y)
```

So this line of code

```
L[row][col] = image.getRGB(row, col);
```

need to be changed

```
L[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row);
```

Comment: @lina You are welcome. It will be nice if you mark my answer and Pierre's answer as useful.

Answer (score 0):

You inverted the order of X et Y in `getRGB()` method.

Try with :  `L[row][col] = image.getRGB(col, row);`

Comment: @lina You are welcome. It will be nice if you mark my answer and v.ladynev's answer as useful ;)